# How to add Flag to a rendered View

Tags: views, flags

I've set up the default Flag (bookmark) and have added the proper links to my node.tpl.php pages so that the flags show up properly.  Is there any way to add the same link to a rendered view (page?) I tried using views-view.tpl.php and adding the following code:

`<?php print flag_create_link('bookmarks', $node->nid); ?>`

But that doesn't work because the rendered view is not a node, of course.  What I'm trying to do is allow users to bookmark a rendered page view just like they can do with any other node.

Comment: is your view of fields? (can you add fields?)

Comment: Yes, it is -- but I'm not looking to add a flag to *each* item, rather I need one flag for the entire page.

Comment: `but I'm not looking to add a flag to each item` what is your view displaying? multiple nodes? or only 1 node?

Comment: Multiple nodes -- news articles, in this case.

Comment: so you want the flag for the page you're on, or for each news article?

Comment: Just a single flag for the rendered page view that displays all articles (i.e., a way to bookmark the "read all news" page.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just a single flag for the rendered page view that displays all
>   articles (i.e., a way to bookmark the "read all news" page.)

ok then doing it the way you were doing it, is the way to go.

`$node->nid` alone won't return the nid, you need to to use [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/6) function

```
<?php

if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
  // Get the nid
  $nid = $node->nid;

print flag_create_link('bookmarks', $nid);

}

?>
```

**Note 1:** If you're using a page view, the above won't work since it cannot fetch an nid since page view's don't have node id's. In order to get it to work, you can create a block view, and then create a node where you insert your block view. Then since the node has a nid, it's able to fetch the node id.

**Note 2:** You can ignore all the comments below, as they were due to using a page view (see note1)

Comment: Unfortunately with that I get Notice: Undefined variable: nid in include() (line 35 of /var/www/mysite.dev/public_html/sites/all/themes/mytheme/views-view.tpl.php).  I'm assuming that's because menu_get_object() tries to return a nid from a path, when the path is not in fact a node but instead is an on-the-fly rendering of several nodes (news articles, in this case) created by Views.

Comment: humm.. it should return the path of the page/node you're on. Not what's on the view. Are you using a Page view or a Block view? If you're using a page view, then that explains the error.

Comment: try just using `print $nid;` to see if you still get the error.

Comment: Yes, it's a page view.  I tried <?php print $nid; ?> on my views-view.tpl.php and I get the same error.

Comment: @SeanCunningham sorry the `<?php ?>` placement was screwed up. [I fixed it now](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/193341/revisions).

Comment: Unfortunately I had already spotted that and I get the error message despite fixing that issue.

Comment: If you enable php filter and select php as your text format and paste this code on a node body, do you get the error?

Comment: No, in that case it works fine.  I'm assuming that's because it is actually a node that's being called. In the view, there is no node to call, presumably.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot this was a page view, which explains why it can't find a nid. In order to get it to work, you would have to create a node of article, basic page or any other content type, and insert your view using a block view.

Comment: another solution, would be to pretend your page view is node 1 (assuming you don't want to flag the real node 1 nor display what nodes the user has flagged) and do `<?php print flag_create_link('bookmarks', 1);?>`

Comment: Wow, I'm a little embarrassed that I didn't think of the block-in-a-page idea.  Can you post that as an answer?  I think an answer to the exact question I posted is not possible, so this is a great work around.

Comment: @SeanCunningham updated answer, cheers.

Comment: @NoSssweat ... interesting, but do you really need to digest all comments above to understand the actual answer? Maybe you want to integrate the relevant comments in your actual answer and then cleanup the obsoleted comments? BTW: bienvenue in the world of 5K ...!

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Thx, the **Note:** in the answer, basically takes care of all the comments, but I will add another note pointing that out.